How to Enable ProGuard/R8 for Python Beeware TOGA Apps?
I am using Python with Beeware and TOGA, and I need to obfuscate my script to have it accepted by the Google Play Console. How can I include the Gradle instructions in the pyproject file to enable ProGuard/R8?

I'm not sure if Toga would still work within an obfuscated app, because it accesses Java APIs by name using JNI. But I don't think Google Play actually requires obsfuscation at all. If it isn't accepting your app, please edit your question to give details of what happened.

Friends, for those who have been following the case, I created a script that allows you to use the toga, together with the obfuscation, for the aab.
https://github.com/canalqb/briefcase
